# Get Windows API TitleBar Icons

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I'm working on a project that uses the Qt framework to handle most window drawing. However, I wanted to have some styling in the title bar area, so I ended up having to pull in some of the Windows API in order to do this. My goal is a Chrome-like system of tabs, which are located in the titlebar area. I already have the behavior I want (QWidget tabs up top, with the Win API handling some other window aspects like minimize, maximize, aero snapping, etc).

However, I was wondering how I can get the standard window buttons (minimize, maximize/restore, close) to show. Right now I'm creating my own buttons via a QPushButton positioned in the correct location and using icons provided by me, but I would ideally like to use the native icons.

My question: is there a way to get the icons for these buttons using the Windows API? I was imagining there must be some way to get back the icons as a HICON object, but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For themed controls (those using visual styles) you can use the [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289(v=vs.85).aspx) API function (the class is `"WINDOW"` and the various parts let you draw the individual controls).

For non-themed controls, you can use the [`DrawFrameControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162480(v=vs.85).aspx) API function with the type set to `DFC_CAPTION`.

Comment: Perfect! The DrawFrameControl seems exactly like what I was looking for.